# Form from Fragments and different Managed Beans in PrimeFaces Wizard

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We're making usage of Primefaces `Wizard` component and the forms been included within the Wizard's TABs were declared inside some UI Fragments with their respective Managed Beans. Each one of the Managed Beans contains properties representing some Entities.

What we need to achieve is that, for every completed step, we take the above mentioned Entity property that was previously fulfilled and designate the same Entity property inside the Wizard Managed Bean, and later we may present the Entities data like a summary, so the user would decide whether to proceed or not.

I'm wondering whether there are some other options to accomplish that rather than set a Session variable across the Wizard navigation.

Is the JSF `@ManagedProperty` usage feasible?

Tks.

Comment: There are scopes that have a longer scope than request scope and are shorter than seasion scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: @JasperdeVries and @Kukeltje we're already using `ViewScoped` scope. I know that this particular scope is meant to leave as long as the navigation stays within the same page, but I was wondering whether @ManagedProperty usage would do the work...